# Go-Redis | Redis Pipeline: Empty Pipeline Object and No Values on running pipeline.Exec()

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

```
queueConfig := config.GetConfig().Queue
address := net.JoinHostPort(queueConfig.Redis.Host, queueConfig.Redis.Port)

provider.redis = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     address,
    Password: queueConfig.Redis.Password,
})
client := provider.redis




for _, taskName := range taskNames {
        queueName := getQueueByTask(taskName)

        logger.
            Get(ctx).
            WithField("queue_name_new", queueName).
            Info("QUEUE_NAME_LOGGER")
        queueTaskMap[queueName] = taskName
        cmd := pipeline.LLen(queueName)
    }
    cmds, err := pipeline.Exec()
```

The above code when run does not give any results in cmds, the slice is empty. I tried a bunch of things:

1. Tried accessing the values from the cmd object returned by Llen -> In this instance, the value returned is 0, since Exec() does not populate the values.
2. Tried using Pipelined as well, didn't work.

Context: I am using redis-labs running this code on Kubernetes. Normal redis calls work.

Comment: Its working on my local machine by the way